# How to define a Kafka consumer group starting with a number and use it in Memgraph?

Tags: apache-kafka, memgraphdb

I've noticed that when attempting to create a Kafka stream with a consumer group name starting with a number, it is not accepted. However, if I prepend a letter before the numbers in the consumer group name, it is accepted. Shouldn't the literal following `CONSUMER_GROUP` be treated as a string regardless of whether it starts with a number?

Here's the revised query:

```
CREATE KAFKA STREAM my_stream
TOPICS sales-data
TRANSFORM my_app.sales_transformations
CONSUMER_GROUP group12345abcde
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS 'kafka.example.com:9092'
CREDENTIALS {'sasl.username':'my_username',
             'sasl.password':'my_password',
             'security.protocol':'SASL_SSL',
             'sasl.mechanism':'PLAIN'};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue in [Memgraph GitHub repo](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/446). This is purely a limitation Memgraph has, an easy way to mitigate the issue is to just prefix the name by any valid character.